# Multiple Div Centering

Tags: css, html, center

I've looked at so many posts on this I'm at a loss as to why its not working for me.

```
.firstCell
{
        float:left;
        width:40%;
    text-align:right;
    align:right;
    border:1px solid white;
}

.cell
{
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    align:left;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid white;
}

.newRow
{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}

.container
{
        width:100%;
        background-color:#DEEFF8;
        margin:0px auto;
}
```

So, I basically have this:

```
<div class="container">
*Within this I have sections of like a form*
        <div style="width:400px;border:1px solid black;">
            <div class='firstCell'>File Name:</div>
            <div class='cell'><html:text property="fileName" /></div>
            <div class='cell' style='color:red;'>(Max 50 character)</div>
            <div class='newRow'></div>
            <div class='firstCell'>Copy Book Name:</div>
                <div class='cell'><html:text property="copyBookName"/></div>
            <div class='newRow'></div>
                <div class='firstCell'><html:button property="populateFields" value="Populate Fields" onclick="showFields();"/></div>
            <div class='newRow'></div>
            <div class='newRow'></div>

        </div>

        *So this is one section, what I would like to happen is to position my form elements in this and then have it all be centered on the main div



</div>
```

Comment: You need to learn what the various elements you are using are and how they work. What you posted makes little sense. `Div`'s are block level elements. Which means they take up a row. If this is a form then you should have your html inside a `<form>` element, not a div "container." There are so many things wrong its hard to know where to start :/

Comment: This is only part of my code, the pertiant part. Its all within a form, I just need to position it properly

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle showing the problem?

Comment: You're trying to center the parent div (container). Center the child div. I created a class `center` and added `margin:0 auto` http://jsfiddle.net/2Vy5L/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main .container has 100% width, it doesn't matter if you center it, it will still start drawing it from the very left. The div inside of it that's responsible for the left-aligned box has no id/class, and you're doing no aligning on it. Technically your main container is centered, but everything inside of it is left-aligned.

Comment: In other words change .container width from 100% to 400px. How come you aren't using labels? They are inline elements in the first place. Seems strange to be floating divs into place instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/36ujG/

It's a little hard to understand what you are trying to center. All I did was added `margin: 0 auto` to the child div of container.

Comment: That is what I want, but I do not get the same effect when doing it to mine.

Comment: Perhaps you should post more of your code. It's probably a markup error.

Comment: It works on the fiddle you posted. You will need to make a slightly more in depth test case.

Comment: Ok so the only difference between that and what I actually have is the use of struts textboxes and buttons

Comment: I would just copy the contents of jsfiddle and then readd your buttons.

Comment: The way I made the jsfiddle was copying what I have, just take my jsfiddle and add in like an <html:text> and thats what mine has and it doesn't work